# Draggable component at runtime

Tags: java, swing

i would like to know if it is possible at runtime to list all panel from the application and make them draggable ?  The reason is that i would like to launch my application in one of two modes.  One mode should let me place the component where i want.

Comment: [Introduction to DnD](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/dnd/intro.html)

Answer (score 1):

If I understood your question correctly, I think you're looking for a docking framework.

Consider to build your application on top of the NetBeans Platform (a Swing based RCP), which comes with a docking framework.

Comment: No i m launching one java application from another one.  The launcher application should be able to list all panel in the launched application et make them draggable.  Don't think it is possible but i wanted to ask.